# как создать дополнительное окно в Windows Forms(т.е. внутри одного приложения при нажатии кнопки будет открываться второе окно)

Tags: c#, winforms, всплывающее-окно

Нужно сделать окно, которое при нажатии на кнопку будет открываться второе окно (для добавления нового файла). Допустим будет кнопка "добавить" при нажатии будет высвечиваться\открываться второе окно, в котором нужно будет заполнить несколько текстовых блоков, и при нажатии сохранить, всё это сохраниться в тхт файле. В общем, просто о том как создать второе окно в виндовс форм. Что-то вроде диалогового окна с кнопкой.

Comment: какой элемент является диалоговым окном) так думаю будет легче

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/2.3.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создаете новую форму, добавляете туда все, что вам нужно, далее в главной форме на кнопку "добавить" пишите :

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(); //где Form2 - название вашей формы
frm2.Show();
```

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/2.3.php спасибо за ссылку Bulson